# Seller profile under approval

Tags: office-store

I have created a company seller account in Office Store. Our profile is currently in pending approval state for the last two days.

I have received a "you account is not approved" email two times before and I would love to know what we can do to get it approved. Any best practices? Since there is only a "description" field, I am not sure what all should I add there.

We have created a Microsoft Teams app (the teams version of our popular Slack bot). We are eager to get on the Teams App Store.

Answer (score 0):

Processing times vary (due to the nature of the verification checks done) and depend strongly on whether you register as an individual or as an organization.
If you register as an individual, you will typically see nearly instantaneous turn around.

If you register as an organization however, Microsoft will verify you do really represent the organization that you claim to represent - it may do this by communicating with your organization using non-electronic methods (e.g. snail mail).  We have heard of cases also with larger organizations where the process of internal mail reaching the right individual can be complex.  We often advise: 'it typically takes a number of days, but plan for it taking a couple of weeks'.

The advice above is advisory only and does not represent an ongoing commitment.  Many factors of the verification process are outside of Microsoft's direct control and thus approval turnaround times are subject to change.
If you haven't heard anything for 2 weeks, definitely do reach out to us via our [support channel](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=272975) and we can assist.